# Huge Built-in index space without entities

Tags: google-app-engine

I had 1Gb in built-in indexes. So I put indexes=False in many columns and save the entities again (.put()) but the space of build-in indexes did not change.

So I deleted all of my entity instances and it still remains the same.

How can I remove (format, drop, whatever) all of my build-in indexes in Google App Engine (GAE)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How long have you waited? The display of the storage statistics can take hours (sometimes days) to update.

Comment: I have waited for more than one day, but neither the dashboard is updated.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned the programming language, but I assume it is Python. In this case you need to use appcfg.py with a different action (I assume there are similar tools for the other supported languages):

```
appcfg.py vacuum_indexes myapp/
```

As the [documentation says](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Command-line_arguments): "This command deletes all indexes for the app that are not mentioned in the local version of index.yaml."

Before running the action do an upload of the app, and also double-check index.yaml if it really has all the indices you want. If not, change index.yaml and upload the app again until ready.

Be aware that this might have side-effects to older versions of your app in the case you have already a version of it running in production.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is a Python app.
But I believe the vacuum_indexes command does not work with built-in indexes, which is my problem. I tried to execute that anyway without success.

Comment: By built-in indexes do you refer to the indexes that are build automatically by datastore (for simple queries) or to the indexes that are created automatically when you run the app on local development-server? The command should work on all of them. How many indexes does your index.yaml file define? And how many can you see in the appengine console and what's their status? (e.g. "serving")

Comment: "built-in indexes" I mean "build automatically by datastore (for simple queries)".

For custom indexes (defined in the indexes.yaml file) I am not having any problem. It appears only one index defined and serving correctly.